# Javascript Html.Checkbox onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox

I tried below event in order to reach onchange of checkbox.

```
 @Html.CheckBox("AutoCalculateMandate", true , new { onchange = "AutoCalculateMandateOnChange" })
```

**Javascript:**

```
function AutoCalculateMandateOnChange() {
    alert("working");
}
```

When i try above javascript code , alert never displays nothing(not working).

How can i enable/disable below input on Html.Checkbox value changed ?

```
<input type="text" id="LevyFee" class="form-control" data-required="true" ">
```

Any help appreciates.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be `onchange = "AutoCalculateMandateOnChange()"` instead `onchange = "AutoCalculateMandateOnChange"`!

Comment: how can i get selected value of checkbox and enable/disable input ? thanks also please answer i will accept best answer

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but can someone tell me what language/framework the `@HTML` is? I've never seen this before in javascript, so just curious.

Comment: @JonathanM This is ASP.NET's Razor syntax - `Html` is an instance of type `HtmlHelper`, and the `@` sign allows for inline code inside markup.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks. I've added ASP.NET to the tag list.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get checkbox as a `element` in your function by passing `this` as a reference see updated markup below

```
<input type="checkbox" value="check" id="AutoCalculateMandate" onchange = "AutoCalculateMandateOnChange(this)"/>
<label for="AutoCalculateMandate">
    Auto Calculate
</label> <br />
```

Since you're using MVC so it can be achieved like this:

```
 @Html.CheckBox("AutoCalculateMandate", true , new { onchange = "AutoCalculateMandateOnChange(this)" })
```

**javascript**

```
function AutoCalculateMandateOnChange(element){
     document.getElementById("LevyFee").disabled = element.checked;    
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp2F7/1/)